# Body represents a Section when related to child footer or header elements?

Tags: html, tags

Very simple and fast good practice doubt. As W3C states, the *header* and *footer* tags should be equivalent to their parent *section*, where as for every *header* or *footer* elements there should be only one parent *section*, so the browser understands that those specific *header* and *footer* tags as the header and footer of that specific *section* of the page.

My question is, with this in mind, can the *body* be considered a *section*, letting do something like this correctly:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <footer></footer>

  <section>
    <header></header>
    <footer></footer>
  </section>
</body>
```

Or should a *section* be always an actual *section*, where the correct coding practice would be like this:

```
<body>
  <section>
    <header></header>
    <footer></footer>
  </section>

  <section>
    <header></header>
    <footer></footer>
  </section>
</body>
```

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: Do you have a link to your source for that quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on sectioning content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/content-models.html#sectioning-content-0) is slightly unclear about this.  The only elements that are sectioning content

> content that defines the scope of headings and footers

are `article`, `aside`, `nav`, and `section`.  However, `blockquote`, `body`, `details`, `fieldset`, `figure`, and `td` are [sectioning *roots*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/sections.html#sectioning-root), which can have their own outlines.

There is also an example on the page

```
<body>
    <header>
    ...
    </header>
    <footer>
    ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

...so all of this indicates that you are good to go with `<header>` and `<footer>` in `<body>`, and in point of fact this is different than if you had another section because those on the body would be higher up in the outline than sibling sections.

Another thing to keep in mind based on the spec is that those "sectioning root" elements do not affect the outline of their ancestors (although they will be lower than ancestor roots).

For example:

```
<section>
    <header>head</header>
    <fieldset>
        <header>head2</header>
    </fieldset>
</section>
```

In this case "head" and "head2" are on the same level in the document outline because `<fieldset>` is a sectioning *root*.  If it were `<section>` instead, it would be nested in the "head" node.  You can confirm this [with this handy web utility](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/)

Comment: I have already tried some html 5 outliners, but none of them clarified me, as they ignore the **header** and **footer** that are direct children of the **body**.

Answer (score 1):

W3C HTML5 CR says that the `body` element is a [sectioning root](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#sectioning-root), so there is no reason to wrap its content in a `section` element. It would even be misleading, since it describes the `section` element so that it “represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.” It’s pointless to group everything into one group.

On the other hand, there is no evidence of browsers actually caring the least about the “semantics” of `section`, `header`, etc. Modern browsers just have some default rendering rules for them, that’s all; older browsers ignore the tags and just render the content as if the tags were not there.